# Design Firewall Software

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, .net-3.5

How can I design a Firewall software?

The design should have a layered approach.

Comment: And what do you mean by layered approach? 
If your firewall is just something that blocks/unblocks particular ports - it won't be actually layered. Maybe you're thinking of NIDS/NIPS?

Comment: Plez send the codz? . . . Closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First analyze [this rfc](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3093.html). Like the best April 1. jokes, it is totally true.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really expect such kind of question to be answered, do you? Seems like you haven't put efforts into trying to solve your own question.

Analyze your requirements - and design accordingly. If you come up with your thoughts here - you'll have a better chance that someone could help you.